# Есть ли функция мультивставки/специальной вставки в Termius?

Tags: ssh

В приложении SecureCRT есть функция специальной(мульти) вставки. То есть, когда вставляешь текст в SecureCRT выходит окно мульти вставки, фото ниже:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В этой мульти вставке очень удобно менять текст, когда работаешь с конфигами портов(интерфейсов) и тому подобное.

Перешел в Termius. Очень нравится программа. Единственный нюанс, который меня беспокоит, есть ли такая же функция в Termius?